# Execute linux shell command using PHP script and display in browser?

Tags: php, linux, shell, browser, command

[Executing unix shell commands using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631600/executing-unix-shell-commands-using-php)
[Running shell commands using PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240411/running-shell-commands-using-php-script)
[Execute a shell command through php and display it in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744058/execute-a-shell-command-through-php-and-display-it-in-browser)
I have already referred to the above links. But, I'm experiencing an issue in displaying the linux shell command process in the browser.
My linux command: top -n 1 and wanted to display them using php in the browser..

```
myscript.php
<?php
$var = shell_exec('top -n 1');
echo "<pre>$var</pre>";
?>
```

Now, when I refresh my browser, I'm unable to see the output in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see your problem Rana.
There some shell commands in linux needed to be set along with the TERM enviroment variable.
`top` is one of them.
In addition -b flag must be used in order to get the result from the output buffer, that in this case is the terminal...
Try this code:

```
<?php
$var = shell_exec('TERM=xterm /usr/bin/top -n1 -b');
echo "<pre>$var</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Hey Andreas, thats worked!!. I appreciate your efforts. Thanks alot. Now I can execute the shell command with the php script and display it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since the user browser is not an interactive terminal then we have to execute your last command in every postback, in order to simlate the linux `top` command.

Comment: Hi Andreas, so what can we perform at this point to execute the top command using my php script.  I wanted to display the info on browser once the php script shell_exec command is requested.

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks OK, let's make sure that your environment is correctly set up  by changing the script to do something very simple. Try replacing all code with something like

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
```

If that works, then some further debugging: Are you on a shared webhost where PHP is possibly configured to disable execution of scripts? See if `shell_exec` is disabled [as detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3938155/276949) (replace the string `exec` with `shell_exec`).

Comment: Hi Martin, my script is working well with ls -l and other linux commands. But only the top command is not working.